# Extra newlines added

Tags: python

I want to add a text to a specific location in a file. When I add it, extra spaces would be added. In here, I want to add "mango" text below the "orange" text. To do that I used this code.

```
import fileinput

file_name = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/WebVIM/test_file.txt'

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=1):
    if 'orange' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace(line, line+'\n'+'mango'+'\n')
    print(line)
```

Before execute this code the text file looks like this.

```
apple
orange
banana
```

After executing this code

```
apple

orange
mango

banana
```

But the results I want is

```
apple
orange
mango
banana
```

How do I do that ???

Comment: If you remove the trailing \n from the mango string. It gets rid of the newline after. I am not too sure about the newline before

Comment: If I did not use them, the text will be added to "orange" text. (orangemango)

Comment: You can use the one before mango, you do not need the one after mango.

Comment: Then there would be a new line between apple and orange

Comment: Please see the solution I proposed below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from your print statement. That is what is applying newlines. Try the following

```
import fileinput
import sys
file_name = 'test.txt'

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=True):
    if 'orange' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace(line, line+'\nmango\n')
    sys.stdout.write (line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending two new blank lines (`\n`) in your string replacement.

Comment: If I did not use them, the text will be added to "orange" text. (orangemango)